# Page Title Based on Class/Function Variable PHP

Tags: php, function, class, dynamic, page-title

New to classes, and I'm having an issue dynamically changing a page's title. I think I may know what the issue is, but I don't really know what to do in order to fix the problem. I have two pages, `admin.php` (where the class is housed) and `display-admin.php` (displays what the user sees). Within `admin.php` this is what I have:

```
class Admin {
  public $title;

  public function login() {
    require("login-form.php");

    return $this->title = "Login";
  }

  ...
}

$o = new Admin();
```

This is what I have within `display-admin.php`:

```
<?php
  include_once("admin.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php
      if(isset($o->title)) {
        echo "<title>My Site | " . $o->title . "</title>";
      } else {
        echo "<title>My Site</title>";
      }
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      ...

      switch($action) {
        case "login":
          $o->login();
          break;
        default:
          $o->displayPages();
      }

      ...
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The title always stays as `My Site`. It never adds the title needed. Now, when I tested echoing `$o->title` at the end (before the `<\body>` tag), it displayed the string I passed. Is this because I am trying to echo the variable before calling the function? If so, how do I fix in order to display the title, and have my content displayed within the body?

Thanks in advance for the any/all help/suggestions.

Comment: First of all. Your class is doing too much. Usually when you make a class it means *do one thing well* not "do everything related to this thing well". They're called objects for a reason. Think of them like real world objects. Page object (page title here). Authenticator object (login logic only, not includes), etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it isnt work because  $o->title doesnt exist.
It is created in your "login()" method, and this is after your

```
if(isset($o->title)) {
```

So you can do this:

```
class Admin {

      public $title;

      public function __construct() {
         $this->title = "Admin";
      }
    }
```

You can do it per example in the constructor of your Admin Class.
The constructur is a magic method. It will be automatically called directly if you created your class.
Hope this will help you.

If you create an object from class Admin the title will be change into 'Admin'
In your Admin Page you can do this:

```
$o = new Admin();

echo "<title>".$o->title."</title>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. For some reason when I test it on [writecodeonline.com/php](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) it works, but doesn't work on my site. I don't understand why. I would like for it to change whenever a function is called. For example, when displaying the login form the title is "Admin | Login," and if the login is successful, it calls the displayPages() function and the title would be "Admin | Pages."